# FineUploader uploads to Azure stall on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, azure-storage, fine-uploader

I'm trying to get FineUploader to upload directly to Azure Blob Storage.

I followed the instructions, setting up a demo page with the uploader on it, configured my blob storage account for CORS, and setup an SAS server. Everything seems to work as expected on desktop browsers and my iOS devices, but uploads with my Android devices seem to stall out consistently somewhere around the 8 megabyte mark.

Sometimes the stall is never recovered from, other times it seems to recover, uploads another ~8 megs and stalls again. In either case, it seems stuck on a PUT for 2.2 minutes. I'm not sure if there's any significance to this duration, but it's very consistent in my testing so far.

I've tried with chunking disabled and enabled with a size of 4 megs, and it doesn't seem to have a significant impact on the outcome as far as I can tell.

I've tried on 2 Android devices (4.3 and 4.4) on 2 wifi networks and 4g with the same outcomes.

I have pages with the uploader embedded on it exposed at the following URLs:

http://fineuploadertest.blob.core.windows.net/cdn/index.htm (4 meg chunks)

index2.htm (chunking disabled) and index3.htm (1 meg chunks) are in the same directory if you want to check them out.

I'm running out of ideas at this point, has anyone else run into this or have any additional ideas I can try out?

Below is some debug output I obtained via Chrome remote debugging for an attempt (with chunking) that failed.

PUTs 1-7 succeeded in 2-4 seconds each, put 8 was stalled for 2.2 minutes. The stated error was "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR", but I'm not sure if that's actually significant or just a default branch in the error handling.

```
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Parsing template
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Template parsing complete
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Rendering template in DOM.
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Template rendering complete
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Received 1 files or inputs. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Attempting to validate image. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 1-1048576 of 27179814 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting GET SAS request for a PUT REST request related to file ID 0.0. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending GET request for 0.0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] GET SAS request succeeded. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting Put Block request for 0.0 = part 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending PUT request for 0.0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Put Block call succeeded for 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunked upload request succeeded for 0, chunk 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunk 0 for file 0 uploaded successfully. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 1048577-2097152 of 27179814 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting GET SAS request for a PUT REST request related to file ID 0.1. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending GET request for 0.1 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] GET SAS request succeeded. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting Put Block request for 0.1 = part 1 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending PUT request for 0.1 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Put Block call succeeded for 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunked upload request succeeded for 0, chunk 1 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunk 1 for file 0 uploaded successfully. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 2097153-3145728 of 27179814 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting GET SAS request for a PUT REST request related to file ID 0.2. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending GET request for 0.2 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] GET SAS request succeeded. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting Put Block request for 0.2 = part 2 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending PUT request for 0.2 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Put Block call succeeded for 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunked upload request succeeded for 0, chunk 2 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunk 2 for file 0 uploaded successfully. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 3145729-4194304 of 27179814 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting GET SAS request for a PUT REST request related to file ID 0.3. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending GET request for 0.3 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] GET SAS request succeeded. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting Put Block request for 0.3 = part 3 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending PUT request for 0.3 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Put Block call succeeded for 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunked upload request succeeded for 0, chunk 3 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunk 3 for file 0 uploaded successfully. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 4194305-5242880 of 27179814 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting GET SAS request for a PUT REST request related to file ID 0.4. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending GET request for 0.4 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] GET SAS request succeeded. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting Put Block request for 0.4 = part 4 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending PUT request for 0.4 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Put Block call succeeded for 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunked upload request succeeded for 0, chunk 4 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunk 4 for file 0 uploaded successfully. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 5242881-6291456 of 27179814 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting GET SAS request for a PUT REST request related to file ID 0.5. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending GET request for 0.5 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] GET SAS request succeeded. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting Put Block request for 0.5 = part 5 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending PUT request for 0.5 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Put Block call succeeded for 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunked upload request succeeded for 0, chunk 5 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunk 5 for file 0 uploaded successfully. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 6291457-7340032 of 27179814 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting GET SAS request for a PUT REST request related to file ID 0.6. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending GET request for 0.6 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] GET SAS request succeeded. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting Put Block request for 0.6 = part 6 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending PUT request for 0.6 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Put Block call succeeded for 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunked upload request succeeded for 0, chunk 6 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunk 6 for file 0 uploaded successfully. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending chunked upload request for item 0: bytes 7340033-8388608 of 27179814 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting GET SAS request for a PUT REST request related to file ID 0.7. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending GET request for 0.7 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] GET SAS request succeeded. 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Submitting Put Block request for 0.7 = part 7 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Sending PUT request for 0.7 
PUT https://fineuploadertest.blob.core.windows.net/file//e3cac46f-87b3-474c-a9b…PyNBZRTc%3D&se=2014-06-23T22%3A55%3A08Z&sp=w&comp=block&blockid=MDAwMDc%3D net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR /file//e3cac46f-87b3-474c-a9b8-5393cd2e8b1e.mp4?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=SyXr…NBZRTc%3D&se=2014-06-23T22%3A55%3A08Z&sp=w&comp=block&blockid=MDAwMDc%3D:1
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] PUT request for 0.7 has failed - response code 0 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Put Block call failed for ID 0 on part 7 
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Received error response:  
[Fine Uploader 5.0.2] Chunked upload request failed for 0, chunk 7
```

Comment: Which android version or versions?

Comment: I've tested on a Galaxy Nexus with 4.2 or 4.3 and a Droid Maxx with 4.4

Comment: To clarify: smaller files go up rapidly and chunks get combined into the final file as expected.

Comment: My guess is that any file that has to be broken up into more than one chunk is failing in Android.  Is this correct?

Comment: No, I can definitely see multiple blocks go up and get recombined with files over the chunk size. I may be hitting some kind of limit or boundary condition but I don't think its that specific one. The debug log above was with a chunk size of 1 meg and multiple chunks went up and it failed on the 8th one (which wasn't the last).  You're free to test on my demo site if you have an android device handy.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the fact that your signature server is not returning a valid SAS URL.  For example, your server is returning SAS URLs in its response to Fine Uploader's signature request like this: "https://fineuploadertest.blob.core.windows.net/file//62c...".  Notice the 2 slashes after "https://fineuploadertest.blob.core.windows.net/file".  Can you fix your server to return a valid URL and see if Android still has issues?  I can't exactly explain why it doesn't fail immediately though.

Comment: You may also want to try the same uploads with a non-SSL endpoint for your Azure blob storage container and see if that helps at all.  The protocol error suggests that Android may be having some issues with SSL.

Comment: The double slash didn't seem to have an impact, but changing to an HTTP endpoint seems to resolve the issue 

working example: http://fineuploadertest.blob.core.windows.net/cdn/index3-nossl.htm

I've never run into Android browsers having SSL issues of this type before. For my use case, I don't see a problem with switching to HTTP, but for my own curiosity, have you ever run into this before? Is it Azure specific?

Comment: I found this other [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419256/azure-block-blob-put-fails-when-using-https) which seems to indicate this may be an issue with blob storage's SSL somehow: . I'm going to switch to HTTP for now as my data for this use case has no requirement to be secure. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The issue, as you have noted, is likely Azure-specific.  There aren't a lot of people using Azure (most are using AWS/S3 instead) at this point, so I'm not sure if this is a well-understood issue.  I'd suggest describing your solution as an answer to your own question here, so that others may benefit.

Answer (score 2):

This issue doesn't seem to be fineuploader's fault, but instead appears to be a result of the way SSL works on Azure Blob Storage that only allows a specific amount of data to be transferred in a single HTTPS session (around 5 megs in my testing).

Microsoft has acknowledged the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419256/azure-block-blob-put-fails-when-using-https), but there is no ETA on a fix. I'm not clear why this issue only affects certain implementations of SSL.

In the meantime if you need to allow larger files to be uploaded to azure blob storage from the browser and are running into issues with Android or other browsers the workarounds are:

1) Switch to a non-SSL (HTTP) endpoint if your use case doesn't require the data to be transmitted securely.

2) Don't upload directly to blob storage, but instead upload to a custom endpoint and then have that endpoint copy the file to blob storage. It is fine is this endpoint is hosted in an Azure Website, Web Role or Worker Role, this issue doesn't effect them.

You can find additional information on setting a traditional fineupload upload server [here](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/quickstart/03-setting_up_server.html).